# ASP.NET - Issue with Model Popup while scrolling

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, jquery-ui

I am having a model popup and its works fine. 
There are scroll bars in my page not (in pop up) background page.
When the pop up is visible the background is disabled (default functionality).
In my case,while scrolling the background page , it is disable till some area.
I can say its will work fine, i don't scroll. If I scroll then it I can see that the background is not disabled.
I can't share my applications screenshot, but I find something similar.
Kindly refer the image below.
[image]

http://www.stackprinter.com/topvoted 
This is the output of first link. So the popup grows and in the first look , we can see that the background is disabled
and while scrolling down, the background goes off and feels like a normal one.
How can I prevent this ?

I can use only jQuery. I am using VS2012, ASP.NET 3.5 and C#

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

do something like this to keep focus on your modal even when scrolling:

```
    $('#dialogDiv').dialog({
        height: 600,
        width: 800,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        hide: 'Fade',
        closeOnEscape: false,
        buttons:
        {
            'Ok': function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        $('#dialogDiv').dialog("option", "position", "center");
    });
```